# How do I change a key binding which also has its own prefix key?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I want to change a couple of key bindings for [@wasamasa](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/10/wasamasa)'s [eyebrowse](https://github.com/wasamasa/eyebrowse) package, because I'm on a laptop and the keys <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> aren't easy to access.

The thing is, this package defines a custom prefix for all bindings (<kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-w</kbd>). This confuses me because I don't know if a normal

```
(define-key eyebrowse-mode-keymap (kbd "z") 'eyebrowse-prev-window-config)
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you should be able to change bindings in the `eyebrowse-mode-map` (note, not `...-keymap`) and access them with the default `C-c C-w` prefix:

```
(define-key eyebrowse-mode-map "z" 'eyebrowse-prev-window-config)
```

Now, `C-c C-w z` and `C-c C-w <` (the original default) should both call `eyebrowse-prev-window-config`.

**EDIT:**  I'm a bit surprised that the above code didn't work (just tested it myself), but the following does.  Note that you could also do `(kbd "C-c C-w z")`, but the advantage of the `concat` version is that it will reflect whatever you customized choice of prefix keys is:

```
(define-key eyebrowse-mode-map
  (kbd (concat eyebrowse-keymap-prefix "z")) 'eyebrowse-prev-window-config)
```

Comment: `C-c C-w z is undefined`

Comment: The working of the first version is dependent on how the keymap is defined. In general, it probably won't work.